# How to insert date and time to oracle in java?

Tags: java, html, oracle, date

I know that Oracle has only `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` types.
I have a website made in `Java` and I am looking for a method to insert in an Oracle database dates and time in a table `Appointments`.

For example:

> John has an appointment at his job at 12-jan-2016 21:00.

So, the format will be `day-month-year, hh24:minute`.

I don't want to include in my application a datepicker from the internet if possible.

How can this be done using only JSP/HTML?

unfortunately, HTML5 type "date" isn't supported in IE or Firefox. 
My question is whether or not it is a good idea to use some input fields, and somehow concatenate them into an "preparedSQL statement" that would insert this data into the right place in database?

Comment: Can you post some relevant part of your code please?

Comment: I did not create the page yet. But I just wanted to know how I will do this before starting

Comment: Calling database right from JSP is generally bad practice.

Comment: You are putting in the same place two unrelated codes: the code responsible of the view and the code responsible of inserting dates in database. Secondly, this approach can lead you to maintenance nightmare.

Comment: And how to do it, the right way?

Comment: I knew you would say that... Please have a look to this skeleton code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30941758/363573

Comment: I improved the formatting. Please add more details, make question specific and add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal/good approach anyway. Just make sure all them form a "parseable date/time" fields before going to the database, otherwise it doesn't makes more sense to "try to store something that is (or may be) wrong".

And you do not need to concatenate the fields in the SQL query, when you reach your database tier you should be passing a normal `DateTime` (hopefully...or something similar), so you need only one field  (a `?` in the `PreparedStatement`).

**UPDATE:**

You get the values from the JSP/HTML page; then try to build one of the Java objects specialized in handling date/time routines (`DateTime`, `Calendar`, `Date`...or with some of the *formatters*)...and you are good to go because you would have already something that handles date/time with the input you already got from the user! And that's what you need to use in your `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly...if I have a html input field for each day, month, year, hour, minute, how can I create the preparedStatement?

Comment: Thank you. I will try and come back if I cannot handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton code to get you started.

#### Java classes (optional in your case but not in real life)

```
public class Appointment {
    private Integer id;
    private Date date;
    private List<User> participants;

    // Getters and setters...
}

public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    // ...

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

#### Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/createAppointment")
public class CreateAppointmentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Read form fields
        String date = request.getParameter("date");
        String hour = request.getParameter("hour");

        // Perform sanity check
        // ...

        // Grab a JDBC connection and call a PreparedStatement
        // ...

        // Get response writer
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        // Build HTML code (error cases not shown for code clariry)
        StringBuilder htmlResponse = new StringBuidler();
        htmlResponse.append("<html>");
        htmlResponse.append("<h2>Your username is: " + username + "<br/>");      
        htmlResponse.append("Your password is: " + password + "</h2>");    
        htmlResponse.append("</html>");

        // Return response
        writer.println(htmlResponse.toString());

    }

}
```

#### JSP

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="createAppointment">
        Date: <input type="text" name="date"/> <br/>
        Hour: <input type="text" name="hour"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create appointment" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

To go further, read this: [Handling HTML form data with Java Servlet](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/handling-html-form-data-with-java-servlet)